# AsyncTask with Images and Text

Tags: java, android

I am trying to load the video thumbnails and filename text of videos in a directory.  Since there may be a lot of vidoes in the directory, I need to use AsyncTask.  When I put the code in getView() in AsyncTask, I get a bunch of errors.  Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

String dirNameSlash = "/videos/";
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + dirNameSlash;
String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
String theFile = root_sd + "/videos/";

File dir = new File(path);
{
    assert (dir.exists());
    assert (dir.isDirectory());

}

String[] videoFileList = dir.list();

public class MyThumbnaildapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyThumbnaildapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textfilePath = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.FilePath);
        textfilePath.setText(videoFileList[position]);
        ImageView imageThumbnail = (ImageView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.Thumbnail);

        Bitmap bmThumbnail;
        bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path
                + videoFileList[position], Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
        imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);

        return row;
    }

}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new MyThumbnaildapter(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.activity_main, videoFileList));

    ListView lv = getListView();

}
```

Comment: what are those bunch of errors and where is aysnctask

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? Do you have some logcat to show?
In the mean time, your getView() method could suffer some modifications, you need to implement the ViewHolder pattern, secondly you should try to handle the loading of bitmaps in a separate thread, you don't want to have a laggy listview.

Comment: My variables don't work because they are in the MyThumbnailAdapter class.  I then move parts of that class to AsyncTask, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Volley at the place of AsyncTask . It is very easy to implement as compare to AsyncTask and do a better job as well.

Have a look here for implementation http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library

This is Ficus Kirkpatrick who is explaining Volley in Google I/O 2013 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo

The best Live example of Volley is Google Play Store.

Comment: Isn't this mainly for networking?  The videos are local, and there is actually no networkng involved.